# PHP form update all mysql rows instead of 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE eventcalendar SET Title='$_POST[title]', Detail='$_POST[detail]' WHERE ID='$_GET[ID]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM eventcalendar";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);

echo "<table border=1'>
<tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Detail</th>
<th>Event Date</th>
<th>Date Added</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
    echo "<form action=details.php method=post>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=title value=" . $row['Title'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=detail value=" . $row['Detail'] . " </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['eventDate'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['dateAdded'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
```

This is my code, yet when i try to execute it, it execute all my rows in my table instead of the only 1 I edited. I've searched for like 2 hours but still can't find it. Does any of you know maybe how I can fix this?

Comment: If you can, you should stop using mysql_* functions. They are officially deprecated. These extensions have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about prepared statements instead, and consider using PDO, it's really not hard.

Comment: probably because your `$_GET[ID]` failed.

Comment: If you're using `$_GET[ID]` as your identifier for your update you need to add it to the action of your form.

Comment: Ye i'll try it later definitely but I'm just a newcomer I just started and this is like a small project I have to do. But in the future definitely!

Comment: How do I do that user? So what did I do wrong what do I have to edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to include the ID in the form action.

```
echo '<form action="details.php?ID='.$row['ID'].'" method="post">';
```

This will allow the use of the `$_GET['ID']` value in your update query.

Alternatively, add the ID as a hidden field in your form like

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$row['ID'].'">';
```

And change the SQL query to use `$_POST['ID']` instead of `$_GET['ID']`.

```
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE eventcalendar SET Title='$_POST[title]', Detail='$_POST[detail]' WHERE ID='$_POST[ID]'";
```

Something you also need to look into is escaping the input that you're using with your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the [SQL Injection issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), your problem is that:

1. You're using `$_GET[ID]` in your query, instead of `$_POST[ID]`
2. You aren't posting the ID back to the form at all. Try adding this:

```php
echo "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='{$row[ID]}'>";
```

Comment: I used user2959229's answer and it helped! Thanks for your input tho!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_POST[title]`, `$_POST[detail]` and `$_GET[ID]`are interpreted as plain strings, not as the evaluated value, to get the evaluated value, you have to make use of concatenation.

Update this part :

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
   $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE eventcalendar SET Title='$_POST[title]', Detail='$_POST[detail]' WHERE ID='$_GET[ID]'";
   mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
}
```

to this:

```
if (isset($_POST['update']))
{
   $UpdateQuery = "UPDATE eventcalendar SET Title='". $_POST['title']. "', Detail='". $_POST['detail']. "' WHERE ID='". $_POST['ID']. "'";
   mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, User2959229's answer helped!